# Problem with xelatex in TeXMaker

Tags: errors, xetex

The following code works for me in TeXMaker on Mac OS with XeLaTeX + ViewPDF:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
 \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
 %\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
  \usepackage{pst-3dplot}
  %\usepackage{pst-math}
  % ...
  \begin{document}
   % ...
  \begin{center} 
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(8,5)
  \psdot(1,3)
  \psline(0,0)(8,2)
  \rput(1,3.3){$A$}
  \rput(0.2,0.5){$L$}
  \rput(8, 3){$NICE$}
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{center} 
  % ...
  \end{document}
```

But when using this code with my usual preamble:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, headsepline, pointlessnumbers]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
        \usepackage{mdframed}
        \usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
        \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{float}
        \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
        \newcommand{\RM}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1{}}}
        \makeatletter \g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering        \makeatother
       \usepackage{verbatim}
       \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{booktabs}
       \usepackage{array}
       \usepackage{comment}
       \usepackage{esvect}
       \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
       \usepackage{collcell}

       \usepackage{pst-3dplot}

      %\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

       \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

      %\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}

      \usepackage{pst-3dplot}
     %\usepackage{pst-math}

     % ...



     \begin{document}

     % ...

     \begin{center} 
     \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(8,5)
     \psdot(1,3)
     \psline(0,0)(8,2)
     \rput(1,3.3){$A$}
     \rput(0.2,0.5){$L$}
     \rput(8, 3){$NICE$}
     \end{pspicture}
     \end{center} 

     % ...

     \end{document}
```

I get several errors like "Command \C already defined", "undefined control sequence \ifnum \pdfshellescape..."

Where is the problem?

Comment: unrelated but if using xelatex you should not have either of these lines `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insert `\show\C` after each usepackage you will see that it is undefined until

```
> \C=undefined.
l.19 \show\C

? 
(./hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
> \C=macro:
->\PU-cmd \C \PU\C .
l.21 \show\C
```

That is hyperref defines it. If you do not need that definition then simply use `\renewcommand` rather than `\newcommand` when making your definition, either that or choose a name that *is* free for your command.

Note that you should never use T1 encoding with xelatex (hyphenation will be wrong).

So you should remove

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Also use

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

not

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

You should almost never use the optional argument there as it simply forces graphicx to to use pdftex-specific code even when it has detected that it is running on xetex. the `pdftex` option is harmless but not needed if you are using pdftex and will cause errors in all other cases.

Comment: The error with concerning \C is now away with renewcommand, thank you. But I still get an error like ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ifnum \pdfshellescape
>0 \edef \Gin@extensions {\Gin@extensions ...
l.43 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

Comment: @Jan  you are forcing that error with `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`  which is forcing `graphicx` to use pdftex-specific code even though you are using xetex, delete `[pdftex]`